# cartesian coordinates of a sphere with angles at vector relative to surface of sphere

Tags: plot, coordinates, angle, tooling

```
}
```

}

Hi, sorry if this is a simple problem, but I just can't seem to find any articles or information that exactly matches what I'm looking for.

I am coding in Epson robotics language, but I can convert from c# or python, just need to get the formula. I can handle the rest.

I have a robot that uses a point file X,Y,Z,U,V,W this handles the cartesian coordinates "XYZ" then UVW are the rotation and the latitude and longitude.

I am trying to plot a sphere and have the robot keep the tooling perpendicular to the surface of this sphere.

`float Radius = 30;`
    `float Hx = 0;`
    `float Hy = 0;`
    `float Hz = 0;`
    `float Hu = 0;`
    `float Hv = 0;`
    `float Hw = 0;`

`for(int Lat = 1;Lat <= 180;Lat +=1)`
    `{`
        `for(int Long = 0;Long <=360; Long += 1)`
        `{`
            `Hx = Radius * (Sin(DegToRad(Lat)) * Sin(DegToRad(Long)))`
            `Hy = Radius * (Sin(DegToRad(Lat)) * Cos(DegToRad(Long)))`
            `Hz = Radius * Cos(DegToRad(Lat))`

`Hu = ????????`
            `Hv = ????????`
            `Hw = ????????`

`Go OriginPoint +X(Hx) +Y(Hy) +Z(Hz) +V(Hv) +W(Hw)`
        `}`
    `}`

Comment: I do not understand the problem (not the general problem, but where do you have problem). Could you give us an example (I think you are just asking about a function, so you can give few expected input with expected output, real numbers). In such case we may understand better where is your problem. And which language are you using? Note: Cartesian coordinates are XYZ, so without angles. I think you should do a drawing (and hopefully you will get ideas on what to do).